# Java Reflection - Object is not an instance of declaring class

Tags: java, reflection

This question is being asked everywhere on Google but I'm still having trouble with it.  Here is what I'm trying to do.  So like my title states, I'm getting an 'object is not an instance of declaring class' error.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Main.java

```
Class<?> base = Class.forName("server.functions.TestFunction");
Method serverMethod = base.getMethod("execute", HashMap.class);
serverMethod.invoke(base, new HashMap<String, String>());
```

TestFunction.java

```
package server.functions;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import server.*;

public class TestFunction extends ServerBase {

    public String execute(HashMap<String, String> params)
    {
        return "Test function successfully called";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You're invoking the method with the class, but you need an instance of it. Try this:

```
serverMethod.invoke(base.newInstance(), new HashMap<String, String>());
```

Answer (score 21):

You are trying to invoke the `execute` method on the object `base`, which is actually a `Class` object returned by your `Class.forName()` call.

This would work for a `static` (class) method - but `execute` is a non-static (instance) method.

(It would also work for calling an instance method of an object of type `Class` - but that's not what you are trying to achieve here!)

You need an actual instance of `TestFunction` to invoke the method on, or you need to make the method `static`.

When invoking a static method by reflection, the first argument to `invoke()` is ignored, so it is conventional to set it to `null`, which clarifies the fact that there's no instance involved.

Although your current example method would do the same thing for any `TestFunction` object, in general an instance method could produce a different result for each object - so the `.invoke()` reflection method needs to know which object to run the method on.

Comment: Yes indeed, as described in the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  I wish I could select multiple correct answers for this question.

Comment: @tkcsam - the idea is you select the BEST correct answer ... in your opinion.

Comment: @tkcsam - If you mean ... for rewarding other answers than the one that you accepted, then ... yes, that it true.

Comment: "This would only work for a static (class) method" - that's not true, it would work only for a method of class `java.lang.Class`. Conversely, to invoke static methods one has to pass obj = `null` to `invoke`.

Comment: That's partly right - I'll clarify the answer - but you don't have to pass null to invoke static methods, you can pass anything and it will be ignored. The docs says: "If the underlying method is static, then the specified obj argument is ignored. It may be null."