# How to reflectively invoke PrepareStatement.set

Tags: java, mysql, reflection

I'm trying to reflectively invoke the setXxx method of    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement using the following code.

```
String type = getJavaTypeFromMySqlType(); // this is "String"
Class clazz = type.getClass(); // This is java.lang.String
Method method = com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.class.getDeclaredMethod("set"+type, int.class, clazz);
method.invoke(cnt, clazz.cast(pair.getValue()));
```

The last line throws

> java reflection object is not an instance of declaring class

What am I missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336057/java-reflection-object-is-not-an-instance-of-declaring-class)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is reflection and why is it useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)

Comment: Thank you for down voting just give the explanation though. I do know what reflection is and how to use it, the purpose here is that I'm building a framework to abstract the db interaction. Also @Rao what am I doing differently from the link you have provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a `com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement` as first parameter to `Method.invoke`:

```
method.invoke(pstmt, cnt, clazz.cast(pair.getValue()));
```

The first parameter is the object on which the method is invoked (or null for static methods), the following parameters are the params passed to invoked method.
(Unfortunately the error message of `Method.invoke` does not mention the rejected type, in your case `Integer`).

Comment: Thanks @wero that fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of invoking it reflectively, you can use [`PreparedStatement.setObject(int, Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-) or one of its siblings. If the driver supports the object conversion, then this will work transparently; but be prepared to handle `SQLException` if the type or the conversion to the database type is not supported.