# How to pass a Callback method between different classes at runtime

Tags: java, methods, interface, callback, pass-by-reference

I have spent several days on this niggly problem now and just can't find a solution.

Here is what I am trying to do:
Read a line input and change the interpretation of the data, based on certain 
keywords. These Keywords can be registered dynamically by client Objects. They 
register a **keyword** and a **"callback"** function (for want of a better word).
This "callback" function is invoked when the keyword is encountered, in order to
deal with the input string and return a standardized object.

For this I created a HashMap with the Keyword as key and an Method reference as value.
During the Initialization of the program, all objects, who want to use the service, register with it.

After Initialization the input is read and checked for keywords against my hashmap types. If the type is present there, then the value string is passed to be processed and a standardized Object representation from the string data is returned.

I managed to coax out a method reference by looking up its name and retrieving
the method. The code below can pass, store and retrieve the method, but when trying to invoke it, it produces an IllegalArgument Exception.

During my research I found several reports of similar problems, among others also on this website, but most didn't quite deal with my precise problem.

In [one case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336057/java-reflection-object-is-not-an-instance-of-declaring-class) there was the suggestion that the method invoke cannot work, because there was no instance of the method instanciated. It could be fixed by calling the newInstance method to provide that needed instantiation of the method. It did not work for me, because I cannot get a new Instance from that method reference.

Tried various different approaches from Interfaces through Java8 method references and Listener Patterns. They all allowed the passing of method references, but I always came up to a dead stop because I would have had to declare an instance of the client in XSettings. And that is precisely 
what I cannot do, because I don't what to alter XSettings all the time.

Below is my code:

**Locus.java**

```
---------------------------------
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.function.Function;

...

public class Locus implements StringConverter{
    private long x;
    private long y;

    public Locus(int x, int y) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;     
    }

    public Locus(long x, long y) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;     
    }

    public Locus(String s) {
        super();

        Locus lc = (Locus) convert(s);
        this.x = lc.x;
        this.y = lc.y;
    }

    private long getLongFromString(String s1){
        long res=0L;
        if(s1.matches("[0-9]*$"))       // Integer detected
            res = (long)(Integer.parseInt(s1));
                                        // Long detected
        else if(s1.matches("[0-9]*[lL]$")){
            s1=s1.split("[lL]")[0];
            if(!s1.isempty())              // don't parse empty strings
                res = Long.parseLong(s1);
        }                                // Double detected
        else if(s1.matches("[0-9][0-9]*\\.[0-9]*$"))
            res = (long) Double.parseDouble(s1);

        return res; 
    }

    public Object convert (String s) {
        long x=0, y=0;

        if(s.contains(",")){
            String[] parts = s.split("\\,");
            parts[0] = parts[0].trim();
            parts[1] = parts[1].trim();

            x = getLongFromString(parts[0]);
            y = getLongFromString(parts[1]);
        }
        return createLocus(x, y);
    }

    public static void init() {
        Method method = null;       
        try {
            method = Locus.class.getDeclaredMethod("convert", String.class);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }      

        if(method != null)
            XSettings.setTypeHandler("Locus", method);
    }
  ...
}

---------------------------------
```

**XSettings.java**

```
---------------------------------
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class XSettings {

    // *************************************************
    // Singleton Pattern
    private XSettings(){}

    private static class InstanceHolder {
        public static final XSettings instance = new XSettings();
    }

    public XSettings getInstance() { 
        return InstanceHolder.instance;
    }

    // *************************************************

    static final String cfgFileName="C:\\workspace\\Router\\route.cfg";
                          // Map with the payload data to be queried
    public static HashMap<String, Object> settings = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                          // Map with Key / method-references
    static HashMap<String, Method> typeHandler = new HashMap<String, Method>();

                          // caller method for the object converters 
    public static Object convertToType(String type, String value){
        Object result = null;
      Method method = typeHandler.get(type);

        if(method!=null){  // method exists
            try {
                result = method.invoke(method, value);  // <------ causes IllegalArgumentException
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            result=value;    // No? Default pass back the input string
        }
        return result;
    }
                      // store the method refernce in map
    public static void setTypeHandler(String key, final Method method) {
        typeHandler.put(key, method);
    }
                         // Store a payload key value pair
    public static void set(String key, Object value) {
        settings.put(key, value);
    }
                           // Retrieve a value by key
    public static Object get(String key) {
        return settings.get(key);
    }

    public static void init(){     // read input
        String line;
        try (
            InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(cfgFileName);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            ) 
        {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {    Parse the lines
                String key="";
                String type="";
                String val="";
                line=line.trim();                    // trim back empty space
                System.out.println(line);

                if(line.isEmpty())                   // skip empty lines
                    continue;
                if(line.charAt(0)=='#')              // skip comment lines
                    continue;

                String[] subs = line.split("=",2);   // split at assignment
                    continue;

                subs[0]=subs[0].trim();              // key Part
                subs[1]=subs[1].trim();              // value Part
                String[] subValues = subs[0].split("::", 2);   //Split at type, key section
                if(subValues.length==1){             // empty value
                    key = subValues[0];
                } else if(subValues.length>1){       // normal key, value case
                    type = subValues[0];
                    key = subValues[1];
                } else {                             // no assignment operator, empty value
                    key = subs[0];              
                }   
                subValues = subs[1].split("\"");     // remove double quotes from value part
                if(subValues.length==0){             // no quotes and no value
                    val = "";
                } else if(subValues.length==1){      // no quotes
                    val = subValues [0];
                } else if(subValues.length==2){      // quotes present, stripped
                    val = subValues [1];                    
                } else                               // more than two quotes treat as a string only
                    val = subs[1];

                if(!typeExists(type)){               // check if type is in methodHandler
                    key = subs[0];                             // No: set key back to full L-Value
                    type = "";
                }

                settings.put(key, convertToType(type, val)); // Call converter
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static boolean typeExists(String type) {
        boolean res=false;
        if(type!=null)   
            if(!(type.isEmpty()))
                Object m = typeHandler.get(type);
                    res=(m!=null);

        return res;
    }

...

}
---------------------------------
```

The service function is XSettings and the client is Locus. XSettings reads an 
input file line-by-line, scans it for key Value Pairs. The Key may 
contain the Target Class name. So the line is split into Type, Key and Value.

The interpretation of value differs by type. By default only Strings are stored
away. When other objects register a Keyword and supply the conversion method 
they get picked up and converted into the desired object. So when the key is 
queried the result is the right object right away.

I managed to get the method reference all the way to the invocation point. The 
object looks to be the same in Locus when passing it to the setTypeHandler 
method of XSettings, as well as after retrieval from the HashMap and before 
invocation. Then IllegalArgumentException ...

This might be a very "C"-like way of doing this, but I always thought it was 
relatively efficient and elegant. However if there is a much better Java-like way, I would be thrilled to hear about it.

Thank you for your interest. Really looking forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 0):

I think in XSettings.convertToType you need first to create an instance of the specified type and then invoke the specified method on this instance.

Creating an instance of this type means: Loading the class for this type, search for the default constructor using the reflection api and invoke this constructor to get an instance of this type.

Comment: Thanks Martin for the tip. 
However at the moment I haven't got a clue how to do this.
Will investigate this and report back.

Comment: here is what i changed the invoke line to
...
    result = method.getClass().newInstance().invoke(method, value);
...
no more IllegalArgumentException, now it is InstantiationException.
I guess that could be because there is no empty constructor in that class. Need to check that.

Comment: The solution is that the method is indeed uninstantiated. However getClass returns not the Locus Class but the reflection Class.